# Get custom image size in catalog woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a store, and my products images is **600x400** in product page. But in catalog, the product image size is **200x134**.

**My problem is:** The product catalog get the original image and resize using CSS, but the total image size is the same and my site get slow. I already make a new image size in wordpress configurations to create a small images in the size 200x134 and named a "catalog image size", and now all image i upload is created in this size too.

**My question is:** How i tell the woocommerce to get "catalog image size" in the catalog page and not the "full image size"?

Comment: Are you using a custom Theme?

Comment: Yes. And i know where in the theme is the code of catalog image, but i don't know how i change to get the specific image i talk before.

Comment: You shall show the code displaying the image for help.